# How to know what all classes / jar files a Java application uses

Tags: java, class, jar

I am from C/C++ background and i do have work exp in Java. I am now moving into Java language (as i feel i should have done this long time back). In C/C++, if application has been linked to external shared libraries (.so, .a , .sl), we can know this dependency using 'ld' command.

My question is, does .jar server similar purposes? Like if a java application is dependent on 1.jar, 2.jar etc, does those jar files get 'linked' forever to Java application(resulting in Bigger files, like .a gets liked to c/c++ app resulting in bigger executable) or dynamically (same like .so / .sl gets loaded on the fly and not part of main c/c++ app).

Also, is it possible to list out what all jar files a java application is dependent on?

In java, by default the application imports java.lang.* package, does this package reside inside a jar file? If so, which jar files correspond to that package?

Thanks a lot!

Vipin

Comment: Question one is ready to answer by simple experimentation. Question two, no, which is why things like Maven exist. Question three, check out your JDK or JRE install directories. Look for jar files. Grep through their listed contents. Questions answered!

Comment: The answer can be even more complex if you consider that [1] you may have different classloaders and [2] you may have duplicated classes from different jars and [3] you may specify a class to be dynamically invoked using forName() on execution time

Answer (score 0):

Do things get hardwired into your application? Definitely not. It's your responsibility as developer and deployer to keep track of what jar files are needed by the application.

The default library (as defined in the JDK API docs) is contained in a jar file that's deployed as part of the JVM installation, so you never have to ship those.
Similarly, for Java EE, there's a standard set that the server is required to make available, defined in the Java EE API docs, which you therefore also not need to ship.
Think of those classes as the dynamic libraries that come with the operating system when writing a C application. You don't ship those, you rely on them being there. If they're not, you get an error that the operating system (in case of Java the JVM) is a wrong version.
There are some tools that can extract information on imports from Java classes. And with that information it might be possible to take a directory full of jar files and write software that figures out which of those you need, but you should really just keep track of that as you start writing.

Comment: For JEE  it's not just "need not" ship (the JEE APIs), it's "must not".

Answer (score 0):

You can check the manifest file in META-INF folder. it should contain the declaration for the dependencies of the application. an example would be, class-path are the jars library requirements :

```
manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: melt321
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_35
Class-Path: dependency-jars/log4j-1.2.17.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven
Main-Class: com.example.org.Tester
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

or if jar is using maven, you can check the pom.xml